# How to override method body with reflection in .net 6?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I had a need to write a base class that can itself override methods, adding a wrapper for execution. How to do it?

```csharp
class TestService : BaseService {
    public IResult<object> Test1()
    {
        return Result.Success();
    }
}
class BaseService
{
    public BaseService()
    {
        var currentType = this.GetType();
        var methods = currentType.GetMethods()
            .Where(c => typeof(IResult).IsAssignableFrom(c.ReturnType));
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            // how to implement this functionality?
            method.Body = (params) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    BeforeFunc();
                    method.Body.Invoke(params);
                    AfterFunc();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return Result.Error(e);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I found ways with the help of third-party libraries, I would like to implement this with the help of native functionality

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: You're looking to accomplish [aspect-oriented-programming (AOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).  [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) and [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) are some libraries that can help with that task, but you can't just use reflection to do this.